# Inserting a shape fails intermittently

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word macro that inserts an image into the header.

```
Sub Test()
Dim Shp As Shape
        Filenaam2 = "1L.wmf"
        FolderName = ActiveDocument.Path
        Padnaam = FolderName + "\" + Filenaam2
        Set Shp = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=Padnaam, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Left:=CentimetersToPoints(0), Top:=CentimetersToPoints(0))
        With Shp
        .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind
        .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
        .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
        .Left = CentimetersToPoints(13.7)
        .Top = CentimetersToPoints(2.2)
        End With
End Sub
```

This is a test macro, I want to use this code to insert 30 shapes into my document: different shapes for each section, and different shapes for left/right pages. The shape is a black rectangle that should be positioned on the left or right edge of my page (page is A5, 14.7 cm wide). So the final macro will run through all sections, and insert the correct images in each header.

When I run the test macro on my template document, it works. But when I try to apply this macro to another document, it fails without any error messages. I've confirmed that the macro can find the referenced image.

Comment: are you sure that both documents are in the same folder? are you sure that you have the same document sections?

Comment: The macro looked like it failed because the section in my test document was only one page long. Once I added more pages to the section, the images appeared. I'll have to insert the image in wdHeaderFooterFirstPage for it to appear on the first page of the section. I thought I could skip wdHeaderFooterFirstPage because the section is defined not to use a different first page.